# How to create a dynamic range?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, arima, prediction, range

I have data for the entire last year. It is simply a value of a variable for every minute, grouped by days. What I need to do is take all this data and define a dynamic range - that is, define two values for each minute of a day - lower and upper boundaries -  within which the value will lie (let's say for the 95% confidence interval). It will be used for detecting anomalies.

I thought that this is what [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) does and I tried to implement it using Python Statsmodel library but now I am not sure this is the right tool.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what tool/concept should I use? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the title is misleading, please suggest a better one and I will change it. Dynamic range is just what I call it but it might have a different name in statistics.

Comment: Standard term for this is "prediction interval". Statsmodels includes those for some tsa models under the assumption of a normal distribution. If the distribution is not close to normal than either transforming the observed variable or using percentiles of the (empirical) residual distribution would be better.